# How to pass data from alert dialog to same page in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to pass data from alert dialog.Alert dialog contains textfield,so whatever the user type on the textfield that text should pass to the main page (screen).Below is the code of the alert dialog

```
    Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 42.0),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
                                _showDialog();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),

Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: new Text('// Displays text'););

    void _showDialog() {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            // return object of type Dialog
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
              content: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter the number'
                ),
              )
              ,
              actions: <Widget>[
                // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                   new FlatButton(
                   child: new Text("Cancel"),
                    onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                    new FlatButton(onPressed: (){

                    }, child: new Text("OK"))
                  ],

                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit new solution:

```
// write this in your main page
String onMainPageText;
```

you can display like this in **on your main page!** after clicking the okey in your **_showdialog** method `Text(onMainPageText)`

change your `_showDialog` method with the following code.

```
  void _showDialog() {
    String dialogText;
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: TextField(
            onChanged: (String textTyped) {
              setState(() {
                dialogText = textTyped;
              });
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter the number'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      onMainPageText = '';
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        onMainPageText = dialogText;
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: new Text("OK"))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Old answer:

create a global TextEditingController will handle your problem you can access the text field text with `textEditingConroller.text`

**dont forget to define textEditingController** inside your class

```
class YourMainPageState extends State<YourMainPage>{
  TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();

}
```

```
  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter the number'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
                new FlatButton(onPressed: () {print(textEditingController.text);}, child: new Text("OK"))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

You can display typed text with that code :

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: new Text(texEditingController.text););
```

Comment: Thanks but how to show the text on the main screen which i type in textfield.

Comment: I'm assuming you are calling  `_showDialog` method from the main screen so all you need to do is write that code `TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();`
inside your main screen class  and use the _showDialog method in my answer, and you able to reach the text with `textEditingController.text`

Comment: Thanks,but you are showing this print on logcat.My question is that how to display text on the main page instead of showing in a print.

Comment: Okey post code and comment where you want to display it,I can modify it but basicly you can reach the typed text field with ‘textEditingController.text’

Comment: I have updated the above code and also commented where the text should get.

Comment: Did you try it @mohammednabil ?  If you can't implement that answer maybe I can provide another one! but current answer is really basic too.

Comment: It works but partial.Problem is when i click OK after typing some text it doesn't go to the main screen and displays the text.It only shows the text when i click OK then click Cancel then tap on the screen.

Comment: hey I provide new answer it's working, I hope new answer will be usefull for you. @mohammednabil

Answer (score 0):

The textfield has a parameter called onChanged: you can use that to pass a function

```
TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChange: onChange
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter the number'
            ),
          )
```

in your main screen use this:

```
 void onChange(String text) {
 //do stuff here with text like maybe setState
 }
```