# Prevent AlertDialog method from exiting before returning a value

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm totally new to Flutter and I've been assigned to modify some previously written code.

```
Future<Null> procesar(String code) async {
    txtController.clear();

    switch (mode) {
      case 1:
        processMode1(code);
        break;

      case 2:
        processMode2(code);
        break;

      case 3:
        String expectedLocation = code.substring(0,2);
        print (DateTime.now().toString() +  ": About to enter _showLocationDialog");
        final String receivedLocation = await _showLocationDialog();
        print("Received Location: " + receivedLocation);
        print(DateTime.now().toString() +  ": Just exited _showLocationDialog");

        if (receivedLocation == expectedLocation){
          processMode3(code);
        }
        break;
    }
}

Future<String> _showLocationDialog() {
    print (DateTime.now().toString() +  ": INSIDE _showLocationDialog");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("READ LOCATION"),
          content: TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            onChanged: (String textTyped) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(textTyped);
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Location:',
              hintText: 'Waiting for input...',
            ),
          ),          
        );
      }
    );
}
```

I just need to check that receivedLocation equals expectedLocation before calling method "processMode3()". I display an AlertDialog so the user can enter the "receivedLocation".

The problem is that the _showLocationDialog method ends before I can get the "receivedLocation" value.

These are the "print" messages the console displays:

```
I/flutter (19504): 2019-09-12 13:02:27.384737: About to enter _showLocationDialog
I/flutter (19504): 2019-09-12 13:02:27.399395 : INSIDE _showLocationDialog
I/flutter (19504): Received Location: null
I/flutter (19504): 2019-09-12 13:02:27.416521: Acabo de salir de _showLocationDialog
```

Obviously, I would have expected that "Received Location" wasn't null.

How can I obtain the "textTyped" value before the "_showLocationDialog()" ends?

I think it definitely has to do with async/await/Futures... but none of the articles I've read before has helped me. Here are some links I've read:[Futures, async, await: Threading in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/futures-async-await-threading-in-flutter-baeeab1c1fe3); [AlertDialog Example](https://androidkt.com/flutter-alertdialog-example/); [How to pass data from AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933278/how-to-pass-data-from-alert-dialog-to-same-page-in-flutter)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the *return* state that pointed out @aligator, I had to change the *case 3* code so it looked like this, using *.then*.

The whole new code looked like this:

```
Future<Null> procesar(String code) async {
    txtController.clear();

    switch (mode) {
      case 1:
        processMode1(code);
        break;

      case 2:
        processMode2(code);
        break;

      case 3:
        String expectedLocation = code.substring(0, 2);        
        _showLocationDialog().then((receivedLocation) {
          if (receivedLocation == expectedLocation) {
            processMode3(code);
          } 
        });
        break;
    }
}

Future<String> _showLocationDialog() {
    print (DateTime.now().toString() +  ": INSIDE _showLocationDialog");
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("READ LOCATION"),
          content: TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            onChanged: (String textTyped) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(textTyped);
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Location:',
              hintText: 'Waiting for input...',
            ),
          ),          
        );
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the result of the dialog inside `_showLocationDialog()`.

you need to put a return statement behind showDialog :

```dart
Future<String> _showLocationDialog() {
    print (DateTime.now().toString() +  ": INSIDE _showLocationDialog");
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("READ LOCATION"),
            content: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: (String textTyped) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(textTyped);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Location:',
                hintText: 'Waiting for input...',
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

*also you should use `onSubmitted` on the text field instead of `onChanged` or cache the input from `onChanged` and call `Navigator.of(context).pop(textTyped)` when the editing is done because `onChanged` is called every time a new character is added.*

Comment: You were totally right on the _return_ statement. The reason I'm using the _onChanged_ event is because the input will be read directly from the barcode scanner of a PDA, so I needed to read it at once and avoid users to tap on OK to submit the value. Thank you.